# How to put two views into one tabgroup in eclipse plugin project

Tags: eclipse, plugins

How to put two views into one tab group in eclipse plugin project
looks like two Views are separate , I want to display them as tabs

Any hints will be more than welcome!

Below is an example of plugin.xml

```
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <category
            name="Category "
            id="com.my.plugin">
      </category>
      <view
            name="View One"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            category="com.my.plugin"
            class="com.my.plugin.views.ViewOne"
            id="com.my.plugin.views.ViewOne">
      </view>
        <view
            name="Second View"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            category="com.my.plugin"
            class="com.my.plugin.views.SecondView"
            id="com.my.plugin.views.SecondView">
      </view>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It is best to actually enter code into SO instead of images, as it helps if people want to test it, and increases likelihood of responses

Comment: Please read the help section on asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: What do you mean by "tab group"? Is that what Eclipse calls it?